# Как в цикле создать многомерный массив?

Tags: php

Проходит цикл, и нужно в многомерный массив добавить информацию, например:

```
name => Riga
posY => 54.343434
posY => 57.343425

name => Daugavpils
posY => 53.342346
posX => 56.456677
```

Пробовал следующим образом, но сохраняет только последнее значение в цикле:

```
 $arrPos = array(
    lat => $markPosY,
    lng => $markPosX
  );
```

Comment: А откуда берутся данные для цикла? И куда девается название города?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы на каждой итерации делаете "эта переменная равна этому массиву". И на каждой итерации переменная полностью перезаписывается новым массивом. А нужно "в эту переменную (массив) добавить новый элемент":

```
$arrPos[] = [
    lat => $markPosY,
    lng => $markPosX
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrPos[] = array(
    lat => $markPosY,
    lng => $markPosX
);
```